# How to add the same atributes for all SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, each, geometry

I have two SVG elements:

```
<circle r="260.2" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
<circle r="260.2" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
```

and i want add for them the same cx and cy atributes, so i use each with jquery but i have expected response for only first element, what is wrong?

```
svg_el_obj.each(function(){
    $(this).attr({
        cx: svg_plain_h/2,
        cy: svg_plain_h/2
    })
});
```

thx for help.

Comment: how do you create svg_el_obj ? check his length, must be one if you only get the first, your error is not in the .attr code, also you not need the each => svg_el_obj.attr({});

Comment: Worth pointing out here.  You have the same id for two elements in the same document. The ids must be unique: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: im creating them by JS, and i have two elements bc i see them in my DOM :)

Comment: i have two different ids now and it's not helps

Comment: Here is a fiddle with some additions to fill in the gaps between your description and getting something working.  There is an execute button to click to run the "each" function. http://jsfiddle.net/hWwub/12/

Answer (score 0):

what selector do you use to find your svg elements. Seems like you can find only first one.
You see it's incorrect to use same id for different elements anyway.